# Browser based url rewrite in MFP 7

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, ibm-mobilefirst

is there anyway to configure MFP 7 to block incoming requests based on User agent?

I’m building an application for both desktop browser and iOS on MFP 7. I’ve got a requirement to

1. Allow requests coming from Mobile Devices (From Application only)
2. Block any request that’s coming from browser (Mobile / Tablet / Desktop) that is Not Internet Explorer (For Internal Application Compatibility reasons) and return an static HTML page that says incompatible browser detected.

I achieved this (In valid scenario’s atleast) by putting a Reverse Proxy (Like Apache server) and apply Rewrite (RewriteCond, RewriteRule) rules for sample web app. But, couldn’t manage when load MFP server module pointing to a config XML file.

Comment: What you have with reverse proxy is correct. But what are you trying to do with config XML file?

Comment: Reverse proxy configuration I’ve mentioned is with a sample web app. I’m loading MFP module and managing MFP configuration inside xml file which is currently handling url mapping to correct MFP instance